# In solidity, how can you set a bytes variable to empty

Tags: solidity, bytes

I tried this

```
contract MyContract{
    bytes public data = 0x3333;

    function clearData(){
         data = 0x;
    }
}
```

But solc doesn't like me trying to set data to `0x`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `""`.

```
contract MyContract{
    bytes public data = "0x3333";
    bytes public empty;

    function clearData(){
         data = "";
    }
}
```

Tested using https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity by looking at the value of `data` and `empty`.

Comment: Thanks @AakilFernandes for helping build up a knowledgebase for all!

Answer (score 3):

`delete data;`

Source http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html

> delete a assigns the initial value for the type to a. I.e. for integers it is equivalent to a = 0, but it can also be used on arrays, where it assigns a dynamic array of length zero or a static array of the same length with all elements reset. For structs, it assigns a struct with all members reset.